# Enviar valor oculto em um select

Tags: jquery, html

Existe alguma propriedade no select que quando eu seleciono uma opção na hora de enviar ele envie outro?
Por exemplo:

```html
<form action="teste.php">
  <p>
    <select name="mes" id="mess" class="selectpicker">
      <option>Janeiro</option>
      <option>Fevereiro</option>
      <option>Abril</option>
      <option>Março</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <label>
    <button id="enviark" class="btn btn-default">Gerar Linha do tempo</button>
  </label>
</form>
```

Por exemplo,caso eu selecione Janeiro ele envie 1 ao invés de Janeiro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Utilize VALUE como atributo do OPTION.... dessa forma:

```
  <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
```